# Select specific row but based on another column role

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I tried and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like below

```
+-------+---------------+------------+
| ID     |   Comp.    |    Role   |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 1       |   abc         |     All     |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 1       |   abc         |   Sales  |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 2       |   def         |     All      |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 3       |   zeh         |     All      |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 3       |   zeh         |     TI      |
+-------+---------------+------------+
```

I would like result role based, if one specific id have two role one is **All** and other is **Sales** then I need to consider **Sales** row

The output should be something like this

```
+-------+---------------+------------+
| ID     |   Comp.    |    Role   |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 1       |   abc         |   Sales  |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 2       |    def        |       All    |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 3       |   zeh         |     TI      |
+-------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: please format accordingly.. why do you have 2 versions of sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UNION ALL* will take the place

```
select * from table 
where role <> 'All'
union all
select * from table t
where not exists (
    select 1 from table 
    where id = t.id and [comp.] = t.[comp.] and role <> 'All'
)
order by 1
```

Result :

```
ID  Comp.   Role
1   abc    Sales
2   def    All
3   zeh    IT
```

Comment: id 2 row is not coming by this query

Comment: @NiteeshKumar... By mistake wrong alise assigned to inner query. check edited.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.role = 'Sales'
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.role <> 'Sales' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: i want second row also which have id 2, basically my concern is if  same ID and same Comp have two role, one is All and other is anyone so i want to ignore row which have All role.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have only 2 values for Role ('Sales' And 'All')

```
    create table #tmp(ID INT,Comp VARCHAR(10),Role VARCHAR(10))

    insert into #tmp
    SELECT 1,'abc','All'
    union ALL
    SELECT 1,'abc','Sales'
    union ALL
    SELECT 2,'def','All'


    select ID,Comp,MAX(Role) As Role from #tmp
    Group by Id,comp

    drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Role is not static here only All is static

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding

```
SELECT ID,Comp,Role
FROM table1
WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM table1 GROUP BY ID) AND Role != 'All'

UNION
SELECT ID,Comp,Role
FROM table1
WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM table1 GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID)=1)
```

this is working fine check this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afb5d/22)

Comment: ,no The output should be something like this

+-------+---------------+------------+
| ID     |   Comp.    |    Role   |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 1       |   abc         |   Sales  |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 2       |    def        |       All    |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| 3       |   zeh         |     TI      |
+-------+---------------+------------+

Answer (score 0):

If you have other functions you should add then to the `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT
    ID
    , Comp
    , CASE WHEN role_id = 0 THEN 'All'
           WHEN role_id = 1 THEN 'Sales'
           WHEN role_id = 2 THEN 'TI' 
           ELSE NULL END AS Role
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ID
        , Comp
        , MAX(CASE WHEN Role = 'All' THEN 0
                   WHEN Role = 'Sales' THEN 1
                   WHEN Role = 'TI' THEN 2 END 
                   ELSE -1 END) AS role_id
    FROM 
        t 
    GROUP BY
        ID
        , Comp
    )tmp
```

Comment: your answer is correct but if i have 50 roles in table then every time i need to add it in case condition and when new role will add query will fail.